# Pause in split in beamer

Tags: beamer, split, pause

I cannot get `pause` to work in `split` in beamer. The following is an example and I got two identical slides. I hoped to show the first line in slide 1, and both lines in slide 2. Is there a way to do that? Thank you.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
\begin{split}
x&=1+1 \\ \pause
&=2.
\end{split}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\only` like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
\begin{split}
x&=1+1 \\ 
&\only<2>{=2.}
\end{split}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

For more lines you can apply `\only` to as many elements as needed:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
\begin{split}
x&=1+1 \\ 
\only<2->{y}&\only<2->{=2}\\
\only<3>{z}&\only<3>{=3}
\end{split}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain how to use \only, and how do I show $$x=1+1+1=2+1=3$$ in three lines? What if there are stuff before &, like x&=1, y&=2, z&=3?

Comment: @Delong I updated the answer to show an example with three lines and stuff before the `&`.

Comment: So the '\only<2->{}' mean the stuff inside {} will only show in slides 2 and later (of the current page), and if I have a '\pause' before this equation, I need to add the numbers by 1?

Comment: @Delong Yes, if you'd like to learn more about such overlay commands, you can have a look at the beamer user guide, section "9.3 Commands with Overlay Specifications". There are also automatic ways, so you don't have to do the math yourself, but I think seeing the numbers is more intuitive to learn about overlays.